# NaN out of get duration in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem to get out the duration of an mp4 video file when the html document is ready. My code:

```
(function ($, root, undefined) {        
    $(function () {
        'use strict';
        $(document).ready(function() {

                var duration = $("section:first-child() video").get(0).duration;  
                alert(duration);    

        });
    });
});
```

The script works in firefox but in chrome it returns an NaN. Im not a javascript professional and i use wordpress HTML5 Blank theme.

Thanks for your help and best regards.

Comment: might be because the video is not yet loaded, so it doesn't have that info yet

Comment: `()` not required for first child selector, it is selector not function, remove that

Comment: `$(function () {` is same as `$(document).ready(function() {`, you can remove any one of that.

Comment: may be wait for [loadedmetadata](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/loadedmetadata) event

Comment: Also, you have what looks like an IIFE but its not being invoked. If you dont know javascript you need to get the person who wrote this code to explain it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to preload the video metadata for you to be able to access them. Then, within the [`loadedmetadata`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/loadedmetadata) event, you may access the `duration` as below.

```js
$(function() {
    var $video = $('#video_container').find('video');
    $video.on("loadedmetadata", function() {
     $('#duration').text($video[0].duration);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="video_container">
    <video poster="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/poster.png" preload="metadata" controls="" width="400">
      <source type="video/mp4" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" id="mp4"></source>
      <source type="video/webm" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm" id="webm"></source>
      <source type="video/ogg" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv" id="ogv"></source>
      <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
    </video>
</div>

<div>Total duration : <span id="duration"></span></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! With load metadata it works in all browsers! So the problem was that the video was not loadad and javascript couldnt get the metadata out of it.

Answer (score 0):

you need a listener to get the duration of a video

```
var videoTime = 0;
var currentvideo = document.getElementById('video');
currentvideo.addEventListener('play', function() {
     videoTime= currentvideo.duration;
     console.info(videoTime) // get the duration
});
```